# Override hover styles within hovered element

Tags: javascript, css, hover, uppercase

I have a CSS class

```
.uppercase:hover { text-transform: uppercase; }
```

So whenever I use it the text will transform, but in few cases I want some of the text within not to be uppercased.  ( cancel `.uppercase:hover`).  For example:

`Abc cake smurf cafe Zzz` -> `ABC CAKE smurf CAFE ZZZ`

I want to do this using JavaScript not CSS.

**Update:**

`Abc cake (smurf) cafe Zzz` -> `ABC CAKE smurf CAFE ZZZ`

Comment: can you expand a bit on these 'few cases'? which are the cases you don't want the uppercase for?

Comment: like quotes, usernames, date and time

Comment: it should be possible, but you'll need an exact list of the elements you want to keep lowercase - and write rules to find all these elements - depending on your list of elements, this could become a pretty complicated script...

Comment: So you're saying that I need to have a list of elements that should escape the effect. Hmm! how about using a special character(or set of characters) that indicates where the uppercase shouldn't be applied, For instance '~'. Is that possible ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to your last comment to your question: yes, if you can use some reserved characters you could achieve this without too much trouble:

http://jsfiddle.net/LH7sy/8

```
<a class="uppercase" href="#">everything uppercase, except (this) word</a>


$(document).ready(function () {
     $('.uppercase').each(function() {
        var end = false;
        var s = $(this).html();
        while(end == false) {
            var p1 = s.indexOf('(');
            var p2 = s.indexOf(')');
            if (p1 != -1) { /* if '(' is found in the string */
                var result = s.substring(0,p1);
                result += '<span style="text-transform:none">';
                result += s.substring(p1+1,p2);
                result += '</span>'                        
                result += s.substr(p2+1);
                s = result;
            } else {
                end = true;
            }
        }
        $(this).html(result);
    })
})
```

Comment: @DavidMurdoch i'm not a javascript expert, on the contrary - maybe care to expand on what makes you queezy - and be a bit more constructive? Your previous comment isn't really helpful, not for me, and not for anyone else out there. And that's the point of this site, no?

Comment: :) only one problem. When the page loads the text will be **everything uppercase, except (this) word** instead of **everything uppercase, except this word** :( the special characters disappear after you hover

Comment: Sorry, but the entire thing is just bad form: $("a").html() instead of $(this).html(), the selector isn't cached, all variables are thrown into the global scope, the "reserved" characters being replaced like that just doesn't make any sense, etc. My answer is a much better way of doing this.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand your `var s` version still leaks the `result` variable into the global scope.

Comment: i updated my answer, including the remarks of @DavidMurdoch (+1 for that, glad to have learned something). As also seen in the answer of David, I moved the code to the .uppercase selector instead of :hover - since that doesn't make too much sense indeed.

Comment: if I removed '(' and ')' form the string, the only thing I'll get is a `d`. I'm not canceling `uppercase` all the time + you still see '(' ')' before and after you hover

Comment: i updated my answer, i added a check to see if '(' is found in the string. if you also need to possibility to add multiple lowercase words in one string, we'd still need some extra code...

Comment: Good morning. Okay that's fine, you still see the special characters whether you hover or not. Sorry if I'm not doing anything to help, I'm really week at JS / jQuery

Comment: No problem, i'm doing this because it's good exercise. I see you managed to remove the special characters. I updated you last fiddle, now you can have multiple strings in the main string... http://jsfiddle.net/LH7sy/8/

Answer (score 2):

Overwrite the text-transform value for the items you do NOT want to be uppercase on hover.

With jQuery:

```
$(".uppercase").each(function(){
    // wrap case-insensitive occurrences of the words smurf, blue, and stuff
    // with a span that cancels the affect of the inherited text-transform property
    // from its ancestor's `uppercase` class.
    this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(/(smurf|blue|stuff)/ig, "<span style='text-transform:none;'>$1</span>");
});
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, OP is looking for an answer to exclude some words within the .uppercase elements ('smurf' in the example)

Comment: Could you please explain more

Comment: updated to cancel the affect on only specific words within the element.

Comment: Thx for your code, it answers my original question but :) could you please update it ? Useing special characters to cancel the effect. Something like `i'm big, ^i'm small^` -> `I'M BIG, i'm small`

Comment: Sorry, I will do no such thing. Doing something along those lines is generally bad practice, something I'm not going to encourage. If you can edit the HTML itself already, why do you even need JavaScript? Just wrap the word(s) you don't want upper-cased in a `span`.

Comment: I just assumed that if you could insert `^` and`()` you could insert HTML as well.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5852/discussion-between-david-murdoch-and-shepherd)